# Grid where user makes individual choices in every cell. Is there a better way?

Tags: data-tables, grid

I'm in a new job. The company has a pattern for grids, where choices are not made in a column header. But in each cell individually. I have never seen this before.

So I have a grid now, where one column is a dropdown. But every cell has its own dropdown.

Then another column is a date picker. But every cell has its own date picker. And dates are different.

Then there's a fields that free text input. Again, each cell has its own text.

Then $$$ amounts. Same story.

Has anyone ever seen this before?

Further, I am not sure why a grid is used. Except if they want to see these values, right next to each other.

I can't help but think that there must be a better way to organize this info. Better suited than a grid.

Comment: so there's no column headers to define attributes? Do you have a rough sketch that you can show w/o compromising any company internal data? What are the users trying to solve for or display in this pattern?

Comment: You're basically describing a spreadsheet (Excel). It's a very common pattern, probably the standard for structured bulk data entry. I will assume that the reason they use a grid for this is that the rows and columns are meaningful, so it's the same type of data for a number of different entities - which does suggest a table structure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need alternative to dropdown in each cell](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/119712/need-alternative-to-dropdown-in-each-cell)

Comment: [Duplicate question 2](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/19635/115107), [duplicate question 3](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/24139/115107)

Comment: @Mike M: I don't know what's the pattern trying to solve. No one can tell me that, cause it's just been around for a while. It's not just my project, and one PM is asking for it, and they have a specific reason. It's just a common pattern that everyone's used to. 

Column Headers serve to tell what the column is, to house searching and sorting (filtering is grid-based), and to house an information icon, if there's a tooltip, with helper text.

Comment: @Vitaly Mijiritsky Thank you. Yes, I agree, that makes sense.

Comment: @Danielillo Thanks for sharing that discussion. That's helpful.